# Как правильно создать анимацию в Animate.css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animation

Изучаю [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) и хочу понять на наглядном примере, как реализовать следующую задачу:

1. Имеется элемент 1 (любой), который по умолчанию скрыт.
2. При hover на элемент 2 (любой), элемент 1 с анимацией `flipInX` появляется.
3. При исчезновение hover у элемента 2, элемент 1 с анимацией `flipOutX` скрывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве примера (для изучения, поэтому, хоть он и работает, там есть простор для улучшения).

По ховеру, вешаем класс с анимацией на нужный элемент, по mouseLeave, соответственно, убираем.

```js
const $hover = $('.wrapper .hover-me');
const $show = $('.show-me');

$hover.hover(function() {
  console.log('HOVER!!!!')
  $show.removeClass('flipOutX')
  $show.addClass('show animated flipInX');
}, function() {
  console.log('Mouse LEAVE')
  $show.addClass('flipOutX');
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hover-me {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: black;
  }
}

.show-me {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='hover-me'>11111</div>
  <div class='show-me'>22222</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```